# Is it ok to hold the list of fragments as a class reference in the class extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is it ok to hold the list of fragments as a class reference in the class extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as opposed to instantiating the fragment in `getItem(int position)` based on the position (which basically ensures that only 2 fragments are in memory, and whenever a fragment gets GC'ed invokes getItem again). For example my `ViewPagerAdapter` looks like below

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    List<? extends ViewPagerFragment> fragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<? extends ViewPagerFragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position).getPageTitle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Its ok to hold Fragment objects as it may contain some objects(which is already fetched/created at first time).

**2.** Default it holds 3 fragments in memory **A [B C D] E** (assuming you are at **C** Fragment)

**3.** You can always use [setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

**4.** Never ever hold `View` Objects of that fragment.

Comment: By keeping a variable `List<Fragment> fragments` in the adapter am I keeping references to view objects of the fragments too?

Comment: if you are not using `setOffscreenPageLimit(int)` method then no, you are not holding view objects.. You can check  **A [B C D] E**.. if you are at **C** and got to **A** `onCreateView` is going to execute again means it re-creates views..

Comment: So by just holding reference to fragment instances I am not keeping the memory heavy objects alive then, because when onPause of a fragment is called all memory heavy objects are released?

Comment: you are holding objects, only when you are not creating new instance of that fragment on every `getItem()` call..

Comment: by looking at your code. I can say You are holding objects (but not view objects).

Comment: yea so is it fine? Am I going to get outofmemory exceptions here by holding say 10+ fragments in that list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112290/discussion-between-skadoosh-and-bhargav).

Comment: try with 10+ fragments.. you will come to know OOM if it occurred.. **:) :) :)**